# How to add service dependancies in ASP.NET CORE API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET CORE API so please bare with my limited understand. I am learning about dependancy injection and I am trying to register my services in the start up class. However I noticed that one of my services has an dependancy to another service via constructor. How do I pass this within the configure services method.

Do I just 'new up' a the dependancy class and add it within the constructor.

Here is my implementation in the start up class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddControllers();
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TestAPI", Version = "v2" });
});

services.AddSingleton<IAdminRepository>(new AdminRepository());
services.AddSingleton<IAdminService>(new AdminService(need to add dependancy here));
}
```

Here is implementation in my service class:

```
private IAdminRepository _adminRepository;

public AdminService(IAdminRepository adminRepository)
{
_adminRepository = adminRepository;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply register it like this?: `services.AddSingleton<IAdminService, AdminService>();`

Comment: I was under the impression that you needed to register the service with its dependencies but this works thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to add the dependency explicitly, you just have to register your service with

```
services.AddSingleton<IAdminService, AdminService>();
```

The dependency injection framework will automatically detect the required services for your AdminService.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the dependency explicitly, add a theme like this pattern.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAdminRepository, AdminRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IAdminService, AdminService>();
```

This way, the DI framework will do it wherever needed to create a new instance.

moreover, you can use Addscope or Addtransient if you need it, for example:

```
services.Addscope<IAdminRepository, AdminRepository>();
services.Addscope<IAdminService, AdminService>();
```